# Separating two sets by a $\boldsymbol{\Delta}_3^0$ set

Tags: reference-request, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Let $X$ be a Polish space and $A,B\subseteq X$ be such that $A\cap B = \emptyset$, we know that if there is no $\boldsymbol{\Delta}_2^0$ set separating $A$ from $B$ then there exists a Cantor set $C\subseteq X$ with $A\cap C$ and $B \cap C$ dense in $C$.

I would like to know if we can say something similar on the absence of separating $\boldsymbol{\Delta}_3^0$ sets (maybe we can assume $A,B$ analytic), without invoking simple topological refinements and appealing to the above statement.

In this regard  I know that by a theorem of Louveau and Saint Raymond, if there is no $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_3^0$ set separating $A$ from $B$ (with $A,B$ disjoint and analytic) then for all proper $\boldsymbol{\Pi}_3^0(2^\omega)$ sets $P$ there exists a continuous one-to-one map $\varphi:2^\omega \rightarrow X$ s.t. $\varphi(P)\subseteq A$ and $\varphi(2^\omega\setminus P)\subseteq B$. But can we say something strong on the absence of a separating $\boldsymbol{\Delta}_3^0$ set?

Thanks